# Why the regex "egrep -i '(?=error)' syslog | tee errormsg.txt" does not work?

Tags: regex, grep

I'm trying to put each line which contain 'Error' 'error' 'ERROR' from 'syslog' into the file 'errormsg.txt'
So I use this

```
egrep -i '(?=error)' syslog | tee errormsg.txt
```

But it does not work. I got noting. But I'm pretty sure tht my regex is correct

Comment: Use perl-regexp with `grep -iP`.

Comment: why do you need lookaround instead of just `grep -i 'error'` ? See also: [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try
`egrep -i '(.*error.*)' syslog | tee errormsg.txt`
and you can always check your regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/49LOAz/1)

Comment: Another thing is if i want to highlight error, when i add --color before -i, it also doesn't work. Why?

Comment: @MIKUVOCALOID true, seems that some strange behavior with that.  btw i tried and this pattern works too as well and didn't blow coloring ```egrep --color -i 'error'```

Comment: `egrep` is deprecated in favor of `grep -E` so maybe that's your `--color` problem?